# can not found npoi.xssf.usermodel

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I wanna use npoi to manipulate `.xlsx` files in `VS2012/2010`. To do so I should import `NPOI.XSSF.UserModel`, but when I add the `npoi.dll` and try to import that, there is no `XSSF` type of `NPOI` at Using part. I mean that there is no "`Using NPOI.XSSF`"
Any help?

Comment: can you please post some code of what have you done/tried?

Answer (score 11):

You need to include `NPOI.OOXML.dll` dll to use `NPOI.XSSF.UserModel` namespace